# Generic inside a generic

Tags: java, xml, generics, jaxb

First of all I want to show you what I want to achieve.
I want to Generate a XML file out of classes that will look like the following:

```
<config>
    <criteria name="criteriaName" defaultValue="0">
        <item value="1">
            <criteria name="criteriaName2" defaultValue="">
                <item value="foo">
                </item>
                <item value="bar">
                </item>
            </criteria>
        </item>
        <item value="2">
        </item>
    </criteria>
    <criteria name="criteriaName3" defaultValue="">
        <item value="foo">
        </item>
    </criteria>
</config>
```

Summary:

- Criteria has a name and a default value (wich can be String, int or
  double) and x items as childs.
- An Item has a value, which must be of the same type of the parents criteria defaultValue.
- An Item can also hold another criteria. The type of the defaultValue in the criteria is independent from the parents (item) type

e.g.:

```
criteria (type int)
   item (type int)
      criteria(type String)
         item(type String)
```

I also need this model in form of classes because I want to do some validation with it later on.

Now I struggle at a specific point, let me show you my classes first:

Config:

```
@XmlAccessorType(value=XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="config")
public class Config {

    @XmlElement(name = "criteria")
    private List<Criteria> criteriaList = new ArrayList<Criteria>();

    /*getters and setters*/
}
```

Criteria:

```
@XmlAccessorType(value=XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="criteria")
public class Criteria<T> {

    @XmlAttribute
    private T key;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String display;

    @XmlAttribute
    private T defaultValue;

    private List<Item<T>> items = new ArrayList<Item<T>>();

    public T getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    /*getters and setters*/
}
```

Item:

```
@XmlAccessorType(value=XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="item")
public class Item<T>{

    @XmlAttribute
    protected T key;

    @XmlAttribute
    protected String display;

    @XmlElement
    protected List<Criteria<T>> criteria = new ArrayList<Criteria<T>>();

    /*getters and setters*/
}
```

With that I can make a Criteria of a specific type, which has items of the same type.

Now I want to Insert a Criteria under the Item, that has a different type than the Item, but that is not Possible :

```
    Config config = new Config();
    Criteria<Integer> criteria = new Criteria<Integer>();
    Item<Integer> item = new Item<Integer>();

    Criteria<String> subCriteria = new Criteria<String>();
    //this obviously doesn't work
    item.getCriteria().add(subCriteria); //<--

    criteria.getItems().add(item);
    config.addCriteria(criteria);
```

I also tried something like this declaration(in Item):

```
@XmlElement
protected <U> List<Criteria<U>> criteria;
```

But that is only working for methods, not properties.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pretty close to solving the issue. The main problem is that

```
protected Criteria<T> criteria = new ArrayList<Criteria<T>>();
```

is not correct. By your requirements, criteria don't need not have the same type as the parent  item.
One possibility I see is

```
 protected Criteria<?> criteria = new ArrayList<Criteria<?>>();
```

The only issue is now that I think you are going to get a warning/you will have to cast when you try to insert or get elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

What about this.

Class Item:

```
public class Item<T,U>{

    protected T key;

    protected String display;

    protected Criteria<U> criteria = new Criteria<U>();

    /*getters and setters*/
}
```

Class Criteria:

```
public class Criteria<T> {

    private T key;

    private String display;

    private T defaultValue;

    private List<Item<T,?>> items = new ArrayList<Item<T,?>>();

    public T getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    /*getters and setters*/
}
```

Basically we're saying you have an Item with another type U for the inner Criteria. This way you must specify the Criteria type of an Item object in advance, but you can mix Items with different Criteria types into the same Criteria, like this snippet shows:

```
Criteria<String> c1 = new Criteria<String>();
c1.items.add(new Item<String,Float>());
c1.items.add(new Item<String,Integer>());
```

Comment: Thats a very nice suggestion. However, now there seems to be an issue with marshalling the java objects to XML. I think that JAXB isn't able to process generics.. Note: without generics (Strings) it works as expected (when it comes to marshalling). My solution is now: Create Generics, then do either validation with them or map them to another data structure that isn't generic and marshal them.

Comment: In that way are you able to decouple Criteria's generic type from Item's generic type?

Comment: What I mentioned above is a roundtrip I have to go to get the XML output I want. I should have mentioned, that I only need the generic types at runtime (for validation). In my specific case I will never have to unmarshall the xml back into my schema. Explanation: XML is a configuration for a webservice call. I get the (generic) configuration at runtime and validate those with the fields I got from the caller. The XML part is only for giving the caller a form of "allowed" input fields